# TFS 2017 on premise with jmeter and Azure DevTestLabs

Tags: azure, tfs, jmeter, azure-devtest-labs

Sorry for my verbosity, it is my first ever question here.

We have an On Premise instance of TFS 2017, run our builds and releases through that. Setting up Functional test automation as a set of release steps. We want to also run automated performance tests, with JMETER. 
The tests will use Azure DevTestLabs machines as the agents.

Using VSTS with the cloud based Jmeter is not an option due to firewalls as well as the fact that we use JMeter 4.

Question now is, do I incorporate a JMeter instance in the DevTestLabs machine or do I add JMeter to SourceControl so that we have full control over the JMeter version and plugins? Or do you see a different solution that will work even better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, we have all tools and plugins pre-installed on the test agent machine. But if the tools and plugins can be installed remotely or they are not required installing, then put them in TFS source control also works.

Comment: Since DevTestLabs doesn't have a JMeter artifact I am thinking of either including it in my source control or... moving to a DevTestLabs image with a Docker image on it. Especially since I need JMeter with a few specific plugins I have to deploy it along with the tests I guess.

Comment: If this is the case, have a DevTestLabs image with a Docker image on it would be a good option.